# lógica com vetor portugol

Tags: array, portugol

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém me ajudar fico grato, estou empacado em carregar valores menor que os valores anteriores

```js
Algoritmo "semnome"
    // Disciplina  :  [Linguagem e Lógica de Programação]
    // Professor   : Antonio Carlos Nicolodi
    // Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
    // Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
    // Data atual  : 07/05/2019
    Var
        vetNum:vetor [1..5] de inteiro
        i:inteiro
        vInicio

    para i de 1 ate 5 faca
        leia(vetNum[i])

        enquanto vetNum[i] <= vetNum[i] faca
            leia(vetNum[i])
        fimenquanto
    fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceto para o primeiro compare com o elemento de índice - 1.

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
Var
    vetNum: vetor [1..25] de inteiro
    i: inteiro
Inicio
    para i de 1 ate 25 faca
        leia(vetNum[i])
        se (i > 1) entao
            enquanto (vetNum[i] <= vetNum[i-1]) faca
                escreva("Não pode ser menor ou igual ao anterior. Reinforme:)
                leia(vetNum[i])
            fimenquanto
        fimse
    fimpara
    para i de 1 ate 25 faca
        escreva(vetNum[i], " | ")
    fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```